# What is the overall conviction rate of U.S. criminal courts?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, trial

Of all criminal cases that go to trial *and* end in a verdict in the United States, what percentage result in a conviction for at least one of the offenses being prosecuted?

Comment: By "go to trial" I assume you exclude plea bargains?

Answer (score 1):

68%. [Per the Bureau of Justice Statistics](http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=qa&iid=403).

http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=qa&iid=403

> **What is the probability of conviction for felony defendants?**
>
> Among felony defendants whose cases were adjudicated within the one-year tracking period (89% of cases), 68% were convicted. This includes a 59% felony conviction rate with the remainder receiving misdemeanor convictions. Felony conviction rates were highest for defendants originally charged with motor vehicle theft (74%), a driving-related offense (73%), murder (70%), burglary (69%), or drug trafficking (67%). They were lowest for defendants originally charged with assault (45%).